# Selling/buying limited edition beers online

Tags: laws

I have some opened and unopened beer bottles that are limited edition and is not produced anymore.

I would like to ask if there is any online store like *eBay* where I could sell these beers,  opened empty bottles is OK to sell anywhere, but full bottles with an alcohol cannot be sold depending on privacy policies.

So does anyone knows some kind of place to make such deal?

Answer (score 2):

It is not legal to ship alcohol(beer, wine, or spirits) through the mail across state or national lines unless you have a license. This has to do with each state wanting to get it's tax revenue for the imported alcohol.

That doesn't mean it's not done, it's just less likely for a site that wants to stay in business to allow transactions that would result in it.

I have friends that are part of "exchange programs" that are on various forums. There is a "beertrade" sub Reddit for example.

Comment: "_It is not legal to ship alcohol…across state or national lines_" What about within a state?

Comment: A beverage taxed inside a tax jurisdiction can be transferred, not resold without tax implications, to a 3rd party provided recieving party is legally allowed to have said item.